# POCO Build Problem

Tags: c++, visual-studio, poco

I'm trying to try the POCO library. I downloaded the zip file, and opened the vs solution file named "Net_vs90.sln" on VS 2008. When I try to build the solution, I get this ugly error:

> bla bla bla....
>
> 1>Linking...
>
> 1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot
>   open file 'PocoFoundationd.lib'
>
> bla bla bla....
>
> Linking...
>
> 2>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot
>   open file 'CppUnitd.lib'

I'm surprised, because I haven't done any changes to the code or configurations. What could be the reason?

Comment: Have you looked here http://pocoproject.org/download/ ?

Comment: as the wiki link from the best answer is broken and I myself had the very problem, I decided to write an article about it. Hope it will help someone.
http://blog.novellizator.cz/post/20473945893/how-to-set-up-poco-c-library-in-windows-7-pro-64bit

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing some dependencies from other open source projects.  For example, cppunitd.lib is [CppUnit](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/cppunit/index.php?title=Main_Page).  This may not be included in the files you downloaded (it is often assumed that you should get the latest dependencies yourself)

Comment: CppUnit is included in the zip file. A reference to CppUnit is given in the "Additional Include Directories". Also PocoFoundationd.lib is POCO's own lib. However, it gives error on that lib. too.

Comment: @sahs: "Additional Include Directories" sets the compiler's include path. It doesn't affect which libraries (.lib) are included by the linker

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reminding Romain. The problem was, I hadn't looked at the wiki very well. In one of the wiki pages (below), it says the bat file, in the project, should first be run from visual studio command prompt. Now, the problem is solved :).

http://pocoproject.org/wiki/index.php/FirstStepsWindows